# Generate token without username and password using djangorestframework-simplejwt

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using a non username password based authentication, with the help of a model field, which is passed as `API_KEY` in post parameter. If this value matches with the record in the model. I want to add a custom payload.

I used to the following code, but it asks me for `username` and `password`.

```
class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):

    def validate(self, attrs):
        try:
            request = self.context["request"]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        else:
            request_data = json.loads(request.body)
            api_key = request_data.get("API_KEY")
            try:
                profile = Factory.objects.get(api_key = api_key)
            except:
                raise Exception

        finally:
            return super().validate(attrs)

    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, factory):
        token = super().get_token(factory)

        token['id_key'] = factory.api_key

        return token

class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
```